# iw wlan0 set channel 36 will hang

Tags: debian, iwlwifi, iw

I'm tying to sniff packets with an Intel AC7260 card with Debian Jessie.  It works, but I cannot change channels.  When I enter:

```
iw wlan0 set channel XXX
```

the device will hang and I need to reboot it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a fix.  It turns out the latest firmware caused a problem.  I rolled it back to iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.1.7.0.tgz and it works now.